# How to make ajax call in Knockout after failed validation?

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have knockout doing validation on this input.. I think. I'm unable to set any breaks but it sends the static text from $root.ValidationMessages.Object

Here's the input element below.

```
<input id="objectNumber" name="objectNumber" class="setsize ats-ccnumber valid" 
type="text" placeholder="Number" 
data-bind="value: PaymentOptions.Object.Number>
```

What I'd like to do is somehow send an async ajax call when validation fails passing the input ID and the invalid text that was entered before the text gets wiped out for failing validation. Here' is the KO Handler for the validateObject

```
ko.bindingHandlers.validateObject = {
'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var message = value;
    var when = function () { return true; };

    if (value != null && typeof value == "object") {
        if (value.when != null) {
            when = function () {
                if (typeof value.when == 'function') return value.when();
                return value.when;
            };
        }
        message = value.message;
    }
    addObjectValidation(when, getValueFor(message), element);
},
'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
}
```

};

And here is the addObjectValidation Javascript

```
function addObjectNumValidation(callback, message, element) {
$(element).rules("add", { required: function (x) { return !$(x).attr('disabled') && callback(); }, number2 : function () { return { objectType: $('#objectType').val(), required: !$(x).attr('disabled') && callback() }; }, messages: { required: message, creditcard2: message} });
var messages = $.data(element, 'validationMessages') || [];
messages.push(message);
$.data(element, 'validationMessages', messages);
```

}

I don't see where this is being validated at. First exposure to Knockout. Can anyone explain what's going on if possible and how to send out an ajax call right after validation fails but before the field is cleared?

Comment: Is there any reason to perform an ajax request after the number is valid? It's best practice to only perform the post of the credit card using ajax when a button is clicked.

Comment: There is, data base logging is required for every failed form entry attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation is done by JQuery Validation. It is totally independent from and not related to KnockoutJS.

To get the validation failures everytime the form is validated, listen to `invalid-form` event then access JQuery Validation's errorList member

```
$("form").on("invalid-form", function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target).validate().errorList);
});
```

By the way, if possible, I suggest you to replace JQuery Validation with Knockout Validation.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) plugin would be much better option rather than using JQuery Validation itself. It has support for remote validation with AJAX call. It also based on JQuery Validation so most validation rules are the same

Comment: My hands are tied.. I feel worse now.